# BringToFront a form that is under an another thread while main UI thread is not responding?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I have a legacy application, I cannot change the code that block the main UI thread, and I have to put a kind of message that say "please wait while the process is finishing" with a little animated gif.

I have created a form that will be running under it own thread, `frmBusy.showmodal` and waiting for a signal to close itself, received by the main ui thread.

On that thread I have a timer set at 1 second to do the `application.doevent` to prevent the `ContextSwitchDeadlock` exception

this is working nicely.

the issue is if the client click on show desktop or alt-tab or do something that change the focus while it is not responding and the user alt-tab back to the application, the `frmBusy` form is now hidden.

I have tried the `frmBusy.BringToFront`, doesnt work.

I have tried the usual `frmBusy.Actite` which work but steal the focus if the user actualy want to be somewhere else, no good.

I have tried the `frmBusy.TopMost = true` / `frmBusy.TopMost = false` which work but if the user is actually on another application that form will be over that new application, no good.

is there a way to do what I want or is it simply impossible?

**edit**

Using Banana code, I implemented an example of the issue

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        Form2.InitDialog(this.Handle);
        Thread.Sleep(60000);
    }
}


public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    bool TRunning = false;
    IntPtr _f1Handle;
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    public static void InitDialog(IntPtr F1Handle)
    {
        Form2 F2 = new Form2(F1Handle);
        new Thread(() => F2.ShowDialog()).Start();
    }

    private bool CheckIfForemost()
    {
        return GetForegroundWindow() == _f1Handle;
    }
    public Form2(IntPtr F1Handle)
    {
        TRunning = true;
        _f1Handle = F1Handle;
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    }
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (TRunning)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                if (CheckIfForemost())
                {
                    InvokeIfRequired(this, () => this.TopMost = true);
                }
                InvokeIfRequired(this, () => this.TopMost = false);

                InvokeIfRequired(this, () => this.Text = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " " + GetForegroundWindow().ToString() + " " + _f1Handle.ToString ());
            }
        }).Start();
    }
    public static void InvokeIfRequired(Form control, MethodInvoker action)
    {
        if (control.InvokeRequired)
        {
            control.Invoke(action);
        }
        else
        {
            action();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not do it the other way around? make the frmBusy be the main form, so it will always appear first?

Comment: Whether you want to or not, you should really just refactor the code such that it's not blocking the UI thread at all.  You're only going to continue to create more and more work for yourself until you fix that root cause.  Bite the bullet and fix the real problem.

Comment: @Banana, sadly I cannot change that part of the code

Comment: @Servy, thing is this can happen to about 50 places which mean looking/fixing fews thousand lines of code.

Comment: @Fredou If you're going to be doing much of any maintenance work on the app finding and fixing 50 different places where the UI is blocked is probably worth the effort in order to have an application that can rely on the UI not being blocked, and it's a very significant improvement on the user experience as well.

Comment: You'll have to invest the time sooner or later, usually [like this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents.userpreferencechanged.aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant, the whole system is planned to be rewritten in a few months, for now it maintenance only

Answer (score 0):

you can have the frmBusy check every certain amount of time for the foremost window, and compare it's handle to your main form's handle, and if it fits then pop the frmBusy to front with `TopMost=true` and disable it right away.

Here is a quick example that you can easily adapt to your project:

**Form1**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 F2 = new Form2(this.Handle);
            F2.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

**Form2**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        bool TRunning = false;
        IntPtr _f1Handle;
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        private bool CheckIfForemost()
        {
            return GetForegroundWindow() == _f1Handle;
        }
        public Form2(IntPtr F1Handle)
        {
            TRunning = true;
            _f1Handle = F1Handle;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (TRunning)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    if (CheckIfForemost())
                    {
                        this.TopMost = true;
                    }
                    this.TopMost = false;
                }
            }).Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in my question, i mentioned that topmost is not an option since it will go over other application

Comment: It will not go over other applications, this is why we check what is the foremost window before calling topmost. Check my example in a new project and you will see :). Notice the foremost=false line, we only set it true for a bit to "bump" it to front and set ot false back right away.

Comment: i will play with it again now that i have time, back with result soon :-)

Comment: @Fredou ok so i've done some research and it appears that when the form is not responding and is faded white, it is no longer your form. it is a "ghost window" created by windows to represent your window which is hidden as long as its not responding. in this case, for my solution to work, you need to retrieve the handle of the "ghost window". in windows 7, the ghost window is created by the "dwm.exe" process, which is easy enough to retrieve, however im not sure which process creates the ghost windows on other versions of windows.